# How do I go about solving for Kruskal's union

Tags: c++, graph, minimum-spanning-tree, kruskals-algorithm

I have tried going through the graph and changing every instance of some ID into a newer ID and it still led to a cycle.
What is plan to solve for an acyclic solution?

Comment: Probably you implemented it wrong if you still get a cycle after running the algorithm. Assuming Kruskal's union supposed to mean Kruskal's alorithm for generating MST.

Answer (score 1):

You should never get cycles when adding new edges in the Kruskal's algorithm. If you are adding an edge that connects the same component to itself, you skip that edge. You will *never* get cycles because it won't be a minimal spanning **tree**